# Export Data to CSV but filter it first

Tags: email, powershell

I need to filter and not pull in values that contain X500 in the query from AD.  This will export everything beautifully, but I don't need any thing but the smtp entries.  I will have entries that look like this, which I need

> SMTP:Administrator@domain.com

I have entries like the one below that I don't want.

> X500:/o=domain/ou=Exchange Administrative
>   Group(FYDPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=Mail

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*@*'" -Properties proxyAddresses |
select name, @{ L = 'ProxyAddress_1'; E = { $_.proxyaddresses[0] } },
   @{ L = 'ProxyAddress_2'; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses[1] } },
   @{ L = 'ProxyAddress_3'; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses[2] } } | Export-Csv c:\temp\proxyadlist.csv -Notypeinformation -force
```

Comment: Do the proxy addresses have to appear each in their own column? It would be easier if that didnt matter. You have variable colomn output that is handled easier if you calculate the maximum columns you need first before making your output.

Comment: Not enough info, but you should be using `where` to get rid of the ones you don't want. I don't know enough to help you write a good condition.

Comment: @nkasco That _could_ work but would give column gaps in the output file.

Comment: I actually don't want the proxies to be in different columns.  If I could combine them into one, that would be great.

Comment: That is odd since you are putting them in different columns in your sample.

Comment: The problem is that we have some users that have up to 15 proxyaddresses.

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*@*'" -Properties proxyAddresses | select -first 5 name, @{Name='ProxyAddress';Expression={
    $_.proxyaddresses -match "@" -join ";"
}}` perhaps

Comment: Matt, actually I do need them to be in seperate columns, so I can compare the different strings.  Your code above did in fact remove all references to the X500 references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further refinement could likely be made but I whipped this up and it should do the trick. I wanted to be sure the CSV had no more columns then needed. Wanted to show the basics of what I think you need.

```
# Get all users
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -like '*@*'" -Properties proxyAddresses

# Calculate the number of columns needed for wanted proxyaddresses
$maximumProxyAddresses = ($users | ForEach-Object{($_.proxyaddresses -match "^smtp").count} |  Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

# Build a new object for each user that contains each address we need. 
$users | ForEach-Object{
    $singleUser = $_
    $props = @{Name=$singleUser.Name}

    # Add each proxy address as its own column
    0..($maximumProxyAddresses - 1) | ForEach-Object{
        $props."ProxyAddress$_" = ($singleUser.proxyAddresses -match "^smtp")[$_]
    }

    # Send the hashtable as an object down the pipe.
    [pscustomobject]$props
# Order of variables needs to be corrected.
} | Select (@("name") + (0..($maximumProxyAddresses - 1) | Foreach-object{"proxyaddress$_"}))
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I will try this when I get into the office tomorrow!

Comment: As usual Matt, you provided me with what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want this?

```
$ldapFilter = "(&(proxyAddresses=smtp:*)(proxyAddresses=x500:*))"
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter -Properties proxyAddresses | ForEach-Object {
  $_.proxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -match '^smtp:' }
}
```

This gets all user objects that have both `smtp` and `x500` in `proxyAddresses` attribute, then outputs only the `smtp` addresses.

Comment: I think he wants to filter those out. _I have entries like the one below that I don't want._

Comment: $Users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(proxyAddresses=SMTP:*)" -Properties proxyAddresses |

Comment: I think he wants the users that have both x500 and smtp (all mailenabled users) but only wants the smtp addresses in the output